# Missing modules in apk created with Buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, pygsheets

I have Python program made with Kivy and Pygsheets. It run well on my Windows PC.
I build and APK for Android using Buildozer. It crashes on startup. In Logcat I see an import error in line 6 of pygsheets/authorization.py: `no module named 'google'`.
Here is what I have as requirements in **buildozer.spec** file:
`requirements = python3,kivy,pyasn1,cryptography,pygsheets,google-auth-oauthlib,google-api-python-client`

Out of despair I tried just to copy content of google.oauth2 package into my project folder. Seems like it helped a little: now i don't get `no module named 'google'` message, but have `No module named 'cryptography'` and `No module named 'pyasn1'` instead. But i have them all listed in requirements.

Seems like pygsheets and Kivy modules are being imported fine, but when pygsheets tries to import anything from google, it fails.

What am I doing wrong here? There is no package named 'google' as i understand. But when i install google-api-python-client and  google-auth-oauthlib, it installs all the modules into google folder. At least on Windows PC. Is it any different when buildozer build an apk?